# Find constants α,β,γ,δ such that the limit exists

Tags: limits, functions, systems-of-equations

I have to find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in \Bbb R $ such that
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 1} f(x)  \in \Bbb R$$

where

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{\alpha x^3-(\beta+\gamma)x-(\alpha+\delta)}{(x-1)^2} & x < 1 
\\
\frac{\beta x^2 - \alpha x + (\beta + \delta)}{x-1} & x > 1\end{cases}$$

I know that in order for the limit to exist, the side limits must be equal.
Trying to solve the first side limit, we find that the denominator is 0.  To be able to use De L'Hospital Theorem the nominator must be 0.
So we get the equation: $\alpha - \beta-\gamma-\alpha-\delta = 0$
Doing the same for the other side limit we get: $\beta - \alpha + \beta+\delta = 0$

Is what i am doing correct?
If so, how do i continue to solve this?

Comment: It looks fine so far.

Comment: Looks good so far, two equations in four unknowns... Except the first case of $f(x)$ has a double-zero in the denominator, so you should be able to get a second equation from that case showing a double root of the cubic at $x=1$...

Comment: i don't understand what you mean :S
can you explain please?

Comment: take derivative of numerator of 1st case and only after that plug in $x=1$ to get $0$ this gives you a third equations.